# In DialogBox, after header want line in android studio

Tags: android

Trying to make a menu with options like this one:

[image]

I could only achieve the following:

[image]

Comment: Add xml file for dialog layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Put this xml code below your title label**

```
    <view
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#30111111"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/divider" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your dialog xml

use below xml at the top where you want a line
where #cccccc is the color of line

```
<View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#cccccc"/>
```